# URL rewrite match hyphen word

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have 2 url rewriting rules.

```
<rule name="Rewrite to microsoft-windows">
      <match url="^microsoft-windows"/>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx?name=microsoft-windows"/>
</rule>
<rule name="Rewrite to microsoft">
      <match url="^microsoft"/>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx?name=microsoft"/>
 </rule>
```

Because of the hyphen, only the rule for "microsoft" applies. so

```
http://www.mysite.com/microsoft-windows
```

points to the wrong rule. How do I get it to point to :

```
http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx?name=microsoft-windows
```

And not to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx?name=microsoft
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using only one rule?

```
<rule name="Rewrite rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(microsoft|microsoft-windows)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx?name={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

It will check that the path contain only `microsoft` or `microsoft-windows` and then redirect to `http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx?name={R:1}` where `{R:1}` is a back reference to the matched path.

Comment: The issue is the dash. With your code and the sample I posted, it sees "microsoft-windows" as "microsoft".

Comment: I tested the rule and it works as expected. Just to be sure, can you try with another brother? (I know from experience that chrome keeps the 301 redirections in cache for a while)